# Livewire Installed into App Folder and Does not Update Component

Tags: php, laravel-livewire

First off, I installed livewire in my laravel 10*:

`composer require livewire/livewire`

then created the a search component for:

`php artisan make:livewire SearchUser`

I discovered that the component was created directly in the App/ folder. (app/Livewire/SearchUser.php)

I went ahead to continue working:

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use App\Models\User;
use Livewire\Component;

class SearchUsers extends Component
{
    public $search = '';

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.search-users', [
            'users' => User::where('username', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
                ->orWhere('name', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
                ->get(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

and then:

```
<div>
    <div class="input-box">
        <i class="uil uil-search"> <em class="icon ni ni-search"></em></i>
        <input type="text" wire:model="search" placeholder="Search name or username..." />
   
        <div wire:loading>
            Loading...
        </div>
        @if (!empty($search))
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush custom-list">
                @forelse ($users as $user)
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <a href="{{ route('user.dashboard', $user->username) }}">{{ $user->name }}</a>
                    </li>
                @empty
                @endforelse
            </ul>
        @endif
    </div>
</div>
```

Now when I remove the if block: @if (!empty($search))

the users shows in the result, but when I try to search a user, the search does not update for some reason.

When I log $this->search in the render method, I get:

`[2023-12-23 21:15:47] local.INFO:`    in laravel logs